# the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!\, x^{n}}{(x+a_1)(2x+a_2)\cdots (nx+a_n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $a_n>0$, $x>0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=a>0$

It is desirable to check the convergence of the following series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!\, x^{n}}{(x+a_1)(2x+a_2)\cdots (nx+a_n)}$

for what range of x.

Edit:I found a simple way:

Raabe–Duhamel's test

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$,
Let $ c_{n}>0$

Define

$$ b_{n}=n\left({\frac {c_{n}}{c_{n+1}}}-1\right)$$

If $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty }b_{n}$$
exists there are three possibilities:

if L > 1 the series converges

if L < 1 the series diverges

and if L = 1 the test is inconclusive.

so by some calculations

$$b_n=\frac{n a_{n+1}}{(n+1)x}$$ so $$L=\frac{a}{x}$$

in-hence for $0\leq x<a$ the series converge and for $x>a$ not converge.

But what happen when $x=a$??

Comment: It depends on how the $a_n$ approach $a$. The next step would probably be [Bertrand's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#3._Bertrand%E2%80%99s_test).

Comment: For $a_n=a$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523242.