# What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n! a^n}{(a+1)(2a+1)...(na+1)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n! a^n}{(a+1)(2a+1)...(na+1)}$ with $a>0$ equal to? Or is it even convergent?

So far I've tried the ratio test, Raabe-Duhamel test and root test but none of them worked.

Comment: Regarding convergence, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521104/the-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-fracn-xnxa-12xa-2-cdots).

Answer (score 2):

Dividing the factors in the denominator by the corresponding factors in the numerator yields

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{ka}\right)^{-1}\;.
$$

The terms grow as

\begin{eqnarray}
\exp\left(-\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac1{ka}\right)\right)
&\approx&
\exp\left(-\int_1^n\frac{\mathrm dk}{ka}\right)
\\
&=& n^{-\frac1a}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

so the series converges for $0\lt a\lt1$.

If we don’t trust this analysis in the boundary case $a=1$, we can directly simplify the series in this case as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+1}$, which indeed diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) functions, the summand can be [re]written as $$\frac{n!}{\left(1+\frac1a\right)\ldots\left(n+\frac1a\right)}=\frac{n!~\Gamma\left(1+\frac1a\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+1+\frac1a\right)}=\frac{1}{a}\mathrm{B}\left(n+1, \frac1a\right).$$ Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{n^\alpha\Gamma(n)}=1$ ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General)), the series is convergent if and only if $0<a<1$. Further, for $\alpha>1$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm{B}(n+1,\alpha)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1 t^n(1-t)^{\alpha-1}~dt=\int_0^1(1-t)^{\alpha-2}~dt=\frac{1}{\alpha-1},$$ thus the sum of the given series is equal to $\color{blue}{a/(1-a)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pochhammer symbols
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (i a+1)=a^n \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)_n$$ which makes
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac {n! \, a^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n (i a+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{n!}{\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)_n}$$ which write as a number of gamma function but simplify to
$$S_p=\frac{\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)\, \Gamma (p+2)}{\Gamma
   \left(p+\frac{1}{a}+1\right)}-a}{a-1}$$

Considering
$$\frac{ \Gamma (p+2)}{\Gamma
   \left(p+\frac{1}{a}+1\right)}$$ take logarithms, use Stirling approximation, continue with Taylor series for large $p$ to get
$$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (p+2)}{\Gamma \left(p+\frac{1}{a}+1\right)}\right)=\frac{(a-1) \log (p)}{a}+\frac{(a-1) (2 a+1)}{2 a^2   p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ that is to say
$$\frac{ \Gamma (p+2)}{\Gamma
   \left(p+\frac{1}{a}+1\right)}=p^{\frac{a-1}{a}} \left(1+\frac{(a-1) (2 a+1)}{2 a^2
   p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)\right) $$

I am sure that you can finish.